# inicio de sesion fallido

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json, sesiones

Tengo un formulario para login con ajax, php y mysql.
La cuestion es que funciona solo en localhost
Mi codigo en cuestion: 
index.php

```
<body>
<div class="error">
<span>DATOS INGRESADOS INCORRECTOS. INTENTE NUEVAMENTE.</span>
</div>
<div class="app-container app-theme-white body-tabs-shadow">
<div class="app-container">
  <div class="h-100 bg-plum-plate bg-animation">
    <div class="d-flex h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <div class="mx-auto app-login-box col-md-8">
        <div class="modal-dialog w-100 mx-auto">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="h5 modal-title text-center">
                <h4 class="mt-2">
                  <img src="images/bt.jpg">
                </h4>
              </div>
              <form id="Frm" action="">
                <div class="form-row">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="position-relative form-group"><input name="t_user" required placeholder="Usuario" type="text" class="form-control" autofocus autocomplete="off"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="position-relative form-group"><input name="t_pass" required placeholder="Contraseña" type="password" class="form-control"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer clearfix">
              <div class="float-right">
                <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block botonlg" type="submit" value="Ingresar al Sistema"/>
              </div>
            </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center text-white opacity-8 mt-3">Copyright © 2019 - 2020 Web Services</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="css/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="main.js"></script>
```

loginexe.php

```
<?php

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){

require 'config.php';
session_start();

$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');

$usuario =  $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['t_user']);
$pas = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['t_pass']);

if ($nueva_consulta = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, cliente, nombre, tipo_user FROM usuarios WHERE user = ? AND password = ? AND estado = 'S'")){

    $nueva_consulta->bind_param('ss', $usuario, $pas);

    $nueva_consulta->execute();

    $resultado = $nueva_consulta->get_result();

    if($resultado->num_rows > 0){
            $datos = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
            $_SESSION['user'] = $datos;
            echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'tipo' => $datos['tipo_user']));
    }else{
            echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
    }
    $nueva_consulta->close();
}
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

main.js

```
jQuery(document).on('submit','#Frm',function(event){
"use strict";
event.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
    url: 'loginexe.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('.botonlg').val('Validando...');
    }
})

.done(function(respuesta){
    console.log("respuesta");
    if (!respuesta.error){
        if(respuesta.tipo === 1){
            location.href = 'administracion/';
        }else if (respuesta.tipo === 2){
            location.href = 'atencion/';
        }else if (respuesta.tipo === 3){
            location.href = 'atencion/';
        }
    }else{
        $('.error').slideDown('slow');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.error').slideUp('slow');
        },3000);
        $('#Frm')[0].reset();
        $('.botonlg').val('Intente Nuevamente');
    }
})
.fail(function(resp){
    console.log("resp.responseText");
})
.always(function(){
    console.log("complete");
});
});
```

config.php

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('iphost','user','pass','bd');
if ($mysqli->connect_errno):
echo "ERROR AL CONECTAR BD ".$mysqli->connect_error;
endif;
```

Como les mencione al comienzo, todo funciona bien en mi maquina (localhost) pero en el hosting, ni siquiera da un error en la consola como para guiarme.
Esta demas mencionar, que los datos de conexion a la BD estan correctos y la tabla usuarios tambien con sus respectivos usuarios donde cada usuario tiene un tipo, por ej, el usuario1 es tipo 1 (administrador) y tipo2 (usuario normal) y dependiendo de eso, en main.js se hace la redireccion hacia sus respectivas carpetas dentro del servidor.
Alguien tiene alguna idea del porque pueda estar pasando esto?
Agradezco cualquier ayuda u orientacion con respecto a esto.

Comment: En el hosting no hay logs de php? Sale algo allí?

Comment: @Alfabravo es un hosting compartido.. no veo logs que puedan orientarme a ver cual es el problema

Comment: Siempre suele haber forma de revisar los logs de php, porque tu espacio suele ser algo similar a un virtualhost, separado de los demás. O si usase otro tipo de virtualización, igual los logs se generarían para tu host. Por favor remítete a la documentación sobre el cpanel o equivalente en tu hosting

Comment: ¿Has puesto que se muestren todos los errores, warnings, etc... de PHP? error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');

Answer (score 0):

Estas guardando mal los datos en la variable `$_SESSION['user']`. O en este caso no deberían ser datos sino un solo dato, pero puedes hacer esto:

```php
$_SESSION['conectado'] = true;
```

Comment: ¿Por qué dices que no se puede? No hay ningún problema en almacenar un array en una variable de sesión.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo por qué haces una petición AJAX si luego vas a redirigir con JavaScript:

```
if (!respuesta.error){
    if(respuesta.tipo === 1){
        location.href = 'administracion/';
    }else if (respuesta.tipo === 2){
        location.href = 'atencion/';
    }else if (respuesta.tipo === 3){
        location.href = 'atencion/';
    }
}
```

No tiene sentido que hagas una petición al servidor, esperar respuesta en el cliente y luego según la respuesta redirigir con el cliente. Es mucho mejor hacer la petición al servidor y que el servidor redirija según el resultado de la consulta. Así evitas tiempo de procesamiento y transferencia de datos.

Comment: estimado, segui tus consejos y efectivamente, las redirecciones finalmente las hice del lado del servidor y funciona bien. seguire haciendo pruebas y añadiendo las medidas de seguridad pertinentes para ver que tal se comporta. Saludos y muchas gracias por tus comentarios.